# Android: seekbar change detect by user only

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, seekbar

I use below code:

```
seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
if(seekBar != null) {
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            Log.i("errorCheck", "VOL7: " + seekVolume);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            Log.i("errorCheck", "VOL8: " + seekVolume);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {
            // code here
        }
    });
}
```

`onProgressChanged` work fine, but i cant detect changed by user or by android player

How I can detect user progress change and set new duration to my media player?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `arg2` you're looking for. It is `true` when the user changed the value of seekbar. In fact in the documentation it is referred to as `fromUser`